Using s3gw with nginx proxy
I'm using s3gw to store files and it works well locally. Here is my docker-compose file for local deployment:
services:
  s3:
    image: quay.io/s3gw/s3gw
    volumes:
      - dev-s3:/data
  environment:
    RGW_DEFAULT_USER_ACCESS_KEY: dev
    RGW_DEFAULT_USER_SECRET_KEY: dev
    ports:
      - 7480:7480
    restart: on-failure

volumes:
  mssql-datavolume:
    driver: local
  dev-s3:

But when I deployed it on my droplet and ran nginx server as a proxy, I tried to create a bucket via aws cli but failed. Note that the same approach works when I create the bucket locally. The environment variables S3_ACCESS_KEY and S3_SECRET_KEY are present and should definitely be visible.
Here is a prod docker-compose file:
services:
      s3:
        image: quay.io/s3gw/s3gw
        volumes:
          - dev-s3:/data
        environment:
          RGW_DEFAULT_USER_ACCESS_KEY: ${S3_ACCESS_KEY}
          RGW_DEFAULT_USER_SECRET_KEY: ${S3_SECRET_KEY}
        ports:
          - 7480:7480
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
         - test-network
    
     nginx:
       image: nginx:stable-alpine
       ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "443:443"
       environment:
         SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME}
         S3_URL: ${S3_URL}
       volumes:
         - ./deploy/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates:ro
         - ./etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
         - ./certbot/data:/var/www/certbot
       depends_on:
         - s3
       networks:
         - test-network

    volumes:
      mssql-datavolume:
        driver: local
      dev-s3:

   networks:
     test-network:
       driver: bridge

Here is my nginx template config:
server {
        listen [::]:80;
        listen 80;
        server_name ${SERVER_NAME} www.${SERVER_NAME};
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name ${SERVER_NAME} www.${SERVER_NAME};
         
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/${SERVER_NAME}/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/${SERVER_NAME}/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    
        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
            allow all;
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }        

        location / {
            proxy_pass ${UI_URL};
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        }
        
        location /s3/ {
            rewrite ^/s3/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass ${S3_URL};
            proxy_http_version     1.1;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header       Connection "";
            proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
            proxy_set_header       Host s3;
            proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
            proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
            proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            add_header             Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
        }
    }

Here is a log of nginx container:
2024-10-11T19:34:31.849+0000 7a6126a00700  1 beast: 0x7a6154924770: 172.19.0.8 - - [11/Oct/2024:19:34:31.845 +0000] "HEAD /test-articles HTTP/1.1" 403 0 - "aws-cli/1.35.1 md/Botocore#1.35.35 ua/2.0 os/linux#6.8.0-45-generic md/arch#x86_64 lang/python#3.12.3 md/pyimpl#CPython cfg/retry-mode#legacy botocore/1.35.35" - latency=0.003999994s
2024-10-11T19:34:36.291+0000 7a6120600700  1 beast: 0x7a6154924770: 172.19.0.8 - - [11/Oct/2024:19:34:36.290 +0000] "PUT /test-articles HTTP/1.1" 403 120 - "aws-cli/1.35.1 md/Botocore#1.35.35 ua/2.0 os/linux#6.8.0-45-generic md/arch#x86_64 lang/python#3.12.3 md/pyimpl#CPython cfg/retry-mode#legacy botocore/1.35.35" - latency=0.000999999s
2024-10-11T19:34:40.407+0000 7a6112a00700  1 beast: 0x7a6154924770: 172.19.0.8 - - [11/Oct/2024:19:34:40.393 +0000] "PUT /test-articles?policy HTTP/1.1" 403 120 - "aws-cli/1.35.1 md/Botocore#1.35.35 ua/2.0 os/linux#6.8.0-45-generic md/arch#x86_64 lang/python#3.12.3 md/pyimpl#CPython cfg/retry-mode#legacy botocore/1.35.35" - latency=0.013999981s


Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

403 error code is Access Denied error, have you tried creating the S3 bucket on the terminal using regular aws s3api create-bucket --bucket <bucket name> command with your S3_ACCESS_KEY and S3_SECRET_KEY creds to make sure it is correct?
